# Corda: Enable communication between Corda nodes via the internet

Tags: corda

We are using Corda open source and would like to set up the communication between two nodes via the internet.
We have tried a public `p2pAddress` in `node.conf` with port 80 which did not work. Similarly, using another  `p2pPort` like 10002 is also not working.

Here is an extract of our `node.conf` template:

```
detectPublicIp=false
devMode=true
messagingServerAddress="0.0.0.0:10002"
messagingServerExternal=false
myLegalName="${MY_LEGAL_NAME}"
p2pAddress="corda.mylegalname.company.com:10002"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? The main question is: How can two nodes communicate in the Corda Network via public host names?

Thank you.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Are the two nodes registered to a Corda network? Nodes need to fetch the addresses of the other nodes from the [Network Map](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.9/enterprise/messaging.html#network-map-service) first, otherwise they are not able to find them.

Comment: Hey Alessandro, thank you. Yes, they are registered. We bootstrap the network map and each node has the `node.config` files of all other nodes in its `additional-node-infos` folder.